# How to personnalize backpack content by user role?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm new to backpack and I want to use it for one of my personnal project. For this project, I need to have 2 "admin panel". The first is for a moderator (create/edit/delete some resources, but only resources that he have authorization for) and the second is for an admin (he can do what he wants).

So, I don't know (and didn't find anything on the backpack documentation) how to "personnalize" backpack content and action, given a user role (admin or modo).

I hope I made my problem clear.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

You can show and hide different content to different user roles and/or permissions.
You'll need to "mess" mostly with `sidebar_content.blade.php`, to show and hide menus based on user roles and/or permissions, you can use:

```
@if(!backpack_user()->hasRole('admin'))
...
```

and/or

```
@if(!backpack_user()->hasPermissionTo('edit'))
...
```

This is not enough, you need to ensure this users can access the content even thought the links aren't displayed. You do this in the controller:

```
@if(!backpack_user()->hasPermissionTo('edit')) {
    $this->crud->denyAccess(['update']);
}
```

This is just an example, you may want to `denyAccess`, or `allowAccess` to `['list', 'show', 'create', 'update', 'delete']`.